# Javascript efficient search array for value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, search, object

There's a gap in my JavaScript knowledge here. I want to search an array of objects values for a particular value and return it.

For the year I have been writing JavaScript, I have been implementing it like this:

```
var itemClicked = (function(){

  var retval;

  //Note self.inventory.itemsArray is an array of JS objects

  $(self.inventory.itemsArray).each(function(i){
    if(parseInt(this.id) === parseInt(idOfItem)){
      retval = this;
      return false;
    }
  });

  return retval;

})();
```

It works, but I'm sure as anything there is a more elegant way. Tell me please!

**EDIT - Solution**

Thanks to @gdoron with his answer below.

```
var myVar = $(self.owner.itemsArray).filter(function(){
   return parseInt(this.id) == parseInt(recItemID);
}).get(0);
```

Note: `.get(0)` was added at the end because myVar is wrapped as a jQuery object.

Comment: Define "*more efficient*." Some will misunderstand with "*less characters*"

Comment: So `self.inventory.itemsArray` is an array of selectors or jQuery objects?

Comment: why not index your array by id? They you just need to do `return self.inventory.itemsArray[id]` and avoid the loop entirely.

Comment: What do you mean with efficient? If you're looking for performance, you might want to sort the array by `id` and perform a binary search to achieve `O(n log n)` time complexity - or even switch to a hash map for `O(n)` by storing the items by `id`. If you're just looking to write less code, use `$.filter()`.

Comment: It's an array of Javascript objects. More efficient as in, less characters and not having to execute potentially useless code in a loop until it's found

Comment: @AdamWaite Then `$.filter()` won't suffice either, since it will attempt to find *all* matches - even if you know it should stop after the first.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens, I can't see that loop as the bottle neck. Adam, did suffer suffer from hanging browser or you just want to see other ways?

Comment: @gdoron True, it won't cause a noticeable performance decrease. Optimizations without benchmarks are useless, so unless you have found that those extra iterations cause a problem, you should not have to worry about trying to shave those off.

Comment: I didn't understand that last comment sorry (comment before last now) :/ . I just wanted to make my code more readable mostly, if there's a minuscule performance hit with the extra iterations it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The native jQuery function for this is [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter):

```
$(data).filter(function(){
    return this.id == "foo";
});
```

It's shorter than code you have and more important a lot more readable.
About efficiency, it will iterate all the elements in the set to find as much as possible matches, but I hardly believe it will be the bottle neck of your application, **don't focus on micro-optimisations**.

I suggest you read Eric Lipper blog  about [Which is faster](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

You can also use [`grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) as suggested by @Mattias Buelens:

```
$.grep(data, function(ele){
    retun ele.id == "foo";
});
```

Comment: Native to jq, not native to the language. You might want to be more precise about that.

Comment: @gustafr, I believe it's obvious, but I'll add it.

Comment: This solution unnecessarily wraps the array in a jQuery object though. `$.find` maps to `jQuery.grep` when passing a function, so you're better off using `grep` directly as demonstrated by @Bruno.

Comment: Sticking .get(0) on the end does the trick though. This is the solution that I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Just another option using jQuery's `$.grep( )` function

```
var arr = $.grep( self.inventory.itemsArray, function ( n ) { 
    return n.id == idOfItem;
});
```

The above returns an array of matching array elements. If you just want the first it is easy enough to return `arr[0]` if it exists.

Comment: Doesn't grep return an array, instead of the first matching object?

Comment: As opposed to `$.filter`, `jQuery.grep` doesn't unnecessarily wrap the array in a jQuery object. Both solutions still find *all* matching elements, though. I can't seem to find a native `Array` method or jQuery function which can stop searching after the first match.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens, `each` when returns false stops the iterations. though I would still use `filter` as it's a lot more readable.

Comment: @gdoron The OP commented that he was looking to prevent these extra iteration, but you're absolutely correct that they won't cause a noticeable performance decrease.

Comment: Yeah @gdoron that's what I had in my original to stop the search, thanks. But yeah, .filter is much more readable. Mattias Buelens, thanks for the help too. These IDs come from my data model so I know they are unique so it doesn't really matter. Thanks all for your help. +1 for grep.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm unsure what the function is actually supposed to do (due to the external contexts' variables), the following should be more efficient cycle-wise

```
var itemClicked = (function(){

  var i, array = self.inventory.itemsArray, length = array.length;

  for( i=0; i < length; i++) {

    if(parseInt(array[i].id) === parseInt(idOfItem)){
      return array[i];
    }

  }

  return undefined;

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

> It's an array of Javascript objects

Then do not use jQuery at all. At least, use [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each) instead of building a wrapper object around the array. Still, a simple for-loop is much shorter and more performant:

```
var itemClicked = (function(idnum) {
    var arr = self.inventory.itemsArray;
    for (var i=0, l=arr.length; i<l; i++)
        if (parseInt(arr[i].id, 10) === idnum)
            return arr[i];
})( parseInt(idOfItem, 10) );
```

You might as well think of storing the id properties as numbers right away, so you don't need to convert it each time.